# Having difficulties syncing two tabs at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

while i was working on a simple node.js project that would allow me and a friend of mine to simultaneously play songs from a certain Spotify playlist (i know it can be done easily with the Spotify app, but i just want to make a simple page doing the exact same thing on my own)the code works and all, but i can't get the tabs to sync together at all

INDEX.HTML (i removed the playlist link from the code on purpose)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Music Player</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.3.2/socket.io.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <iframe style="border-radius:12px" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/" width="100%" height="352" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" loading="lazy"></iframe>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
<script>
    const socket = io();
function play() {
    socket.emit('play'); 
}


function pause() {
    socket.emit('pause');  
}

socket.on('play', () => {
    
    console.log('Received play event from the server');
    
});


socket.on('pause', () => {
   
    console.log('Received pause event from the server');
    
});

</script>

</html>
```

SERVER.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);
app.use(express.static('public'));
const projectPath = __dirname;

app.use(express.static(projectPath));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(projectPath, 'index.html'));
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('A user connected');


    socket.on('play', () => {
        console.log('Received play event from a client');
        io.emit('play');
    });

    socket.on('pause', () => {
        console.log('Received pause event from a client');
        io.emit('pause');
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User disconnected');
    });
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I tried chatgpt, it fixed some bugs but it couldn't help with the synchronisation

Answer (score 0):

I have used both `BroadcastChannel`, and a `ServiceWorker`, and clipboard respectively, to achieve that result.

Here's how I achieved synchronizing Tabs and `iframe`s using Clipboard API's https://github.com/guest271314/captureSystemAudio/issues/5#issuecomment-945137118.

Here's how I used an extension `ServiceWorker` to parallel stream the same content to multiple Tabs, synchronized

background.js `ServiceWorker`

```
const start = new Date();
let streams = [];
let data = [...Array(1000)].map((_, i) => i);
let encoder = new TextEncoder();
let resolve;
let promise = new Promise((_) => (resolve = _));
let readable = new ReadableStream({
  start: async (_) => {
    // console.log('Original stream');
    return promise;
  },
  pull: async (c) => {
    while (data.length) {
      c.enqueue(encoder.encode(data.splice(0, 1)));
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }
    c.close();
  },
  cancel: (reason) => {
    console.log(reason);
  },
});

function parallelStream() {
  let controller;
  const stream = new ReadableStream({
    start: (c) => {
      controller = c;
      return;
    },
  });
  streams.push({
    controller,
    stream,
  });
  return stream;
}

async function readStream(rs) {
  return rs
    .pipeTo(
      new WritableStream({
        start(_) {
          // console.log('Starting tab streaming');
        },
        write(value) {
          for (const { controller, stream } of streams) {
            controller.enqueue(value);
          }
        },
        close() {
          console.log('Original stream closed');
          try {
            for (const { controller, stream } of streams) {
              controller.close();
            }
          } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
          }
        },
      })
    )
    .catch(console.error);
}

async function createStream({ id, url }) {
  if (!/^(chrome|chrome-extension):/.test(url)) {
    return await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {
        tabId: id,
      },
      world: 'MAIN',
      args: [`${chrome.runtime.getURL('')}index.html`],
      func: (src) => {
        const url = new URL(src);
        for (const iframe of document.querySelectorAll(
          `iframe[src*="${url.host}"]`
        )) {
          iframe.remove();
        }
        onmessage = async (e) => {
          if (e.origin === url.origin) {
            let bool = false;
            e.data
             .pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream())
              .pipeTo(
                new WritableStream({
                  start() {
                    console.log('start');
                  },
                  write(value) {
                    console.log(value);
                    if (!bool) {
                      //bool = true;
                      // transferableWindow.remove();
                    }
                  },
                  close() {
                    console.log(`Stream closed`);
                  },
                })
              )
              .catch(console.error);
             
          }
        };
        const transferableWindow = document.createElement('iframe');
        transferableWindow.style.display = 'none';
        transferableWindow.name = location.href;
        transferableWindow.src = url.href;
        document.body.appendChild(transferableWindow);
      },
    });
  }
}

async function onClicked(tab) {
  const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({});
  for (const { id, url } of tabs) {
    await createStream({ id, url });
  }
  try {
    readStream(readable); resolve();
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onUpdated);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

async function onUpdated(id, { status }, tab) {
  if (status === 'complete') {
    const { url } = tab;
    try {
      await createStream({ id, url });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
}

async function onMessage(e) {
  if (e.data === 'stream') {
    try {
      const rs = parallelStream();
      e.source.postMessage(rs, [rs]);
      //e.source.postMessage(null);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  } else {
    //e.source.postMessage(null);
    console.log({time: ~~((new Date() - start) / 60000)});
  }
}

function onInstalled(reason) {
  // console.log(reason);
}

function onInstall(e) {
  e.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
}

function onActivate(e) {
  e.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
}

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(onClicked);



chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInstalled);

addEventListener('message', onMessage);

addEventListener('install', onInstall);

addEventListener('activate', onActivate);
```

script.js

```
const { active } = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;

async function handleMessage(e) {
  console.log(e.data);
  if (e.data instanceof ReadableStream) {
    const readable = e.data;
    parent.postMessage(readable, name, [readable]);
    // close();
  } else {
    //await new Promise((_) => setTimeout(_, 1000 * 5));
    //active.postMessage(e.data);
  }
}

navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);

active.postMessage('stream');
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="./script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried with a simple audio file, but it still refuses to sync it

Comment: It works. What exactly did you try?

Comment: Here's an example using `BroadcastChannel` https://plnkr.co/edit/mQrJ2varlr5vQlhB?open=lib%2Fscript.js. For media we can transfer a `ReadableStream` using `window.postMessage()`, or exchange SDP to establish a real-time communication channel for WebRTC.

Comment: i tried the same code you provided